# plpgsql function. How to compare value to set of values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a trigger function.
I wish to check if an `status` is one of (5,6,4,7)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION a()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
begin
    if old.status = (5,6,4,7) then
        do something.
    end if; 
    return old;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

how do I change it to proper syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`IN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN19707) operator:

```
...
if old.status IN (5,6,4,7) then
     do something.
end if; 
...
```

Comment: Isn't IN an operator of query? this is not a query.

Comment: Not sure why you linked to Oracle... lol. Rollback if that's not what you intended. @java Most expressions that are valid in PostgreSQL's SQL are also valid in PL/pgSQL.

Comment: @jpmc26 My mistake I saw tag `PL/SQL` not `PL/pgSQL`. Thanks for edit.

Answer (score 0):

This is [reference of this link](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/100x-faster-postgres-performance-by-changing-1-line/).

It only work with postgresql 9.x

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION a()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
begin
    if old.status = ANY (VALUES (5),(6),(4),(7))) then
        do something.
    end if; 
    return old;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Comment: Using `IN` is a much better (and more readable in my opinion) solution. Plus you don't need to repeat the `values` clause for each value: `= any (values (4),(5),(6),(7))` will work just fine.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Thanks